# How to read multiple files with date in the names using a macro into SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a macro to read multiple files that belong to different fiscal years, for example f2002-03, f2003-04. I tried the following code,but it did not work. I really  appreciate any help.

```
% macro test (start,end); 
% do i=&start %to &end ;  
Filename fromzip ZIP “path\f200&i-0&i+1..dat.gz” gzip;  
Filename temp “path\file&i..txt”;   
.....  
%Mend;
%test (2,18);
```

to get 2002-2003, 2003-2004 and to 20017-2018`

Comment: Does the `xxxx-xx` part of the filename represent year and month numbers (`yyyy-mm`)?  Or is that second digits supposed to be the ending year ('`CCyy-yy`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
%macro test (start,end); 
%local year fname ;
%let start=%sysfunc(putn(&start,z2.));
%let end=%sysfunc(putn(&end,z2.));
%do year=20&start %to %eval(20&end -1);
  %let fname=&year-%substr(%eval(&year+1),3);
  %put &=year &=fname ;
%end;
%mend;
```

Results:

```
738   %test (2,18);
YEAR=2002 FNAME=2002-03
YEAR=2003 FNAME=2003-04
YEAR=2004 FNAME=2004-05
YEAR=2005 FNAME=2005-06
YEAR=2006 FNAME=2006-07
YEAR=2007 FNAME=2007-08
YEAR=2008 FNAME=2008-09
YEAR=2009 FNAME=2009-10
YEAR=2010 FNAME=2010-11
YEAR=2011 FNAME=2011-12
YEAR=2012 FNAME=2012-13
YEAR=2013 FNAME=2013-14
YEAR=2014 FNAME=2014-15
YEAR=2015 FNAME=2015-16
YEAR=2016 FNAME=2016-17
YEAR=2017 FNAME=2017-18
```

You could simplify by making users pass in full year values.

```
%macro test (start,end); 
%local year fname ;
%do year=&start %to %eval(&end -1);
  %let fname=&year-%substr(%eval(&year+1),3);
  %put &=year &=fname ;
%end;
%mend;
%test (2002,2018);
```

Comment: Hi Tim,Thank you very much for your response and sorry for my delay backing to you. Your suggestion works and creates the fnames as I need. Now, when I tried to put the fname in file names i don't get any response. What am I missing here?%macro test (start,end); 
%local year fname ;
%do year=&start %to %eval(&end -1);
  %let fname=&year-%substr(%eval(&year+1),3);
  filename fromzip zip "path\f&fname..dat.gz" gzip;
%end;
%mend;
%test (2002,2018);

Comment: what response did you expect? All you did was define a fileref that points to the zip file. You did not generate any code that would do anything with that fileref (either read from it or write to it). Note that you are reusing the same fileref, FROMZIP, over and over. So only the last one file will be pointed to at the end of the macro. You can turn on MPRINT option to see the generated FILENAME statements in the log.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!